# Can't get valid response with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get a specific response string from a public link [here](http://www.elahmad.com/tv/watchtv.php?id=mbc_max)  to automate the function of getting the valid stream link directly (which can be obtained using dev tools).

If i open the website in browser and navigate to dev tools this is the response i want to get which is in this url (opening the url directly doesn't provide any data , please use the link mentioned above):

> http://www.elahmad.com/tv/watchtv.php

In this image:
[Image From Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Guk.png)

I tried to get the response with python using the following script:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Origin': 'http://www.elahmad.com/tv/watchtv.php?id=mbc_max',
    'Referer': 'http://www.elahmad.com/tv/watchtv.php?id=mbc_max',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}


data = {
    '9c37d4962012cec32e950d14f90021bd': 'mbc_max',
}

response = requests.post('http://www.elahmad.com/tv/watchtv.php',headers=headers, data = data , verify=False)

print(response.text)
```

but i always get "Oops!" as output !  the same thing if opened the url in the browser directly without going through the main url above.

What Am i missing ?

Regards

Comment: Probably a cookie.

Comment: @Amadan, tried with cookies and still no luck !

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was in the request data , every time a fresh data is needed when request is sent .

Regards